# URI.getPath() does not return anything after '#'

Tags: java, uri

I have a URI with path like this :

```
ftp://test:test@someftp/ready123/users/abc/#0#.
```

But the method `getPath()` on the URI returns this:

```
/ready123/users/abc/.
```

I need the whole path to be returned like this :

```
/ready123/users/abc/#0#
```

... So that I can change the working directory(CWD) to the folder #0#. The code is in a generic method and is jarred up which gets used by many other applications. So I have to be very careful when I make changes. I believe anything after # is considered as a fragment, but in this case it is actually the name of a folder.

How do I get the path `/ready123/users/abc/#0#` from the URI object ?

Comment: Code snippets are really helpful while helping.

Answer (score 1):

From the JavaDoc of URI class:

> URI syntax and components At the highest level a URI reference
>   (hereinafter simply "URI") in string form has the syntax
>
> ```
> [scheme:]scheme-specific-part[#fragment]
> ```
>
> where square brackets [...] delineate optional components and the
>   characters : and # stand for themselves.

As such if you want to retrieve everything after the first # you need to use `URI.getFragment()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the hash character with **%23**

```
 URI uir = new URI("ftp://test:test@someftp/ready123/users/abc/%230%23");
 System.out.println(uir.getPath()); // returns '/ready123/users/abc/#0#'
```

Comment: ... but only if the hash and the stuff after it are *really* intended to be part of the path, and not a fragment string.